# How do I parse a JSON column in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, laravel-5

I have a table **estat_proprety** which has two fields *id_proprety* and *equipement_json* as figured below (Figure 01)

***Figure 01 :***

```
   Estat_proprety   |     Type     |   Value
 ------------------ + ------------ + -----------
 id_proprety        |   int        | 01
 ------------------ + ------------ + ----------- 
 equipement_json    |   json       | {Hi-Fi, TV, washing-machine, elevator, iron,...}
```

***Software Version :***
 - MySQL 5.7
 - PHP5
 - Laravel 5.2

***Code :***

```
  foreach($Equipements as $ Equipement){ 

  /* What should I do here for get list of equipment like this {Hi-Fi, TV, washing-machine, elevator, iron,...} ? */

  }

  /* $Equipement_json = ? (I don't know how can I get this format: Hi-Fi, TV,... ) */
  $property = new Property; 
  $property->Equipement_json = $Equipement_json;
  $property->save();
```

***Issue :***
1- Thank you to see my questions in the ***Code***, who I write it in comment.

***Final result :***
1- What I want to get in my table **Figure 01**

Comment: If you want to discuss this further, start another question; include an outline of how you expect to query the table.

Comment: I'm blocked, I can't make a new question !! I have this message : Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.
what can I do ?

Comment: Hmmm... I am not familiar enough with the rules and mechanisms of Stackoverflow to explain what has happened.

Comment: @RickJames ... http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34134432#34134432

Comment: When in doubt, [search meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th). Then read. The link in the pop-up you're seeing could help too.

Comment: I am tied up with stuff now. If @AndrasDeak or Rick or someone can review the version one and after [link to revs](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39605211/revisions) we can see what we can do

Comment: Also see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th .

Comment: The revisions improved the formatting, but did not improve the question.  I guess the question is "How do I parse a JSON column in Laravel"??  (I don't know Laravel, so I can't help there.)

Comment: The wording got rid of "What is the best way to ..." which got it closed for Primarily opinion based. My reopen vote has been cast. Hopefully others can let this user of 5 years not endure a question ban by further downvoting. Over and out.

Comment: It took some effort to get your question undeleted last nite. It would be beneficial if you could join us in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/campaigns) to help resurrect your account.

Comment: @Sourceforest please return to that [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128540) and maybe someone can convey the problem with clarity of this question. In addition you agreed to supply a self-answer so please do that if it is simple and clear.

Comment: @Sourceforest I have the solution but I need to chat with you